# Using sliderMenu like facebook and Tabbar using storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbar, swrevealviewcontroller

Can anyone help me that how can i use slidermenu and `Tabbar` both in `Storyboard`.
I already create `revealViewController` for slidermenu and it work smoothly but when i add `Tabbar` in every screen of `Storyboard` it also work but the problem is that when i navigate the screen from slidermenu `Tabbar` goes (not seen) and when i navigate from `Tabbar` both work properly.
I'm not found this kind of problem so that's why i post this problem here.
so It's my humble request if you face this kind of problem than please help me.
Thank you.!

[image]

This is my `Storyboard`.

Please help me i spent 2 days to fix it but i can't.Thank you..!!!!!

Comment: Why don't you check this. https://github.com/ipup/PPRevealSideViewController

Comment: add the tab bar components in after the tab bar controller

Comment: @DipakSonara I write in my question that my revealSlider work properly but TabBar also work properly but when i use both then tabbar not work properly.

Comment: You can also look into this: https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController. Download  the code and integrate into your app. I found this quite easier and simpler.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik please explain more i can't get you answer throughly.

Comment: @Bikram my reveal already work perfectly so please don't give me git hub suggestion for slider menu...

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA your slider and flow is correct , just u need some modification

Comment: what kind of modification can you tell me? @Anbu.Karthik